# JavaScript todays date + x, bad practice?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm currently working on a project that makes heavy use of dates.

Is there anything inherently wrong with doing this:

```
var TodayPlusSeven = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7));
```

I'm not an expert with JavaScript, but this seems to work. I'm not sure of the negative effects that doing something like this can have.

Thanks.

Comment: +7 what ? seconds ? days ? how is it supposed to know it ?

Comment: @Virus721 Since `getDate()` returns the day of the month, it's obviously days. That's the standard Javascript way to add days.

Comment: `getDate()` and `setDate()` read / write the day of the month of a javascript Date object (`getDay()` would be the day of week)

Comment: Well they should have called it getDay setDay then. It sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you create 3 `Date` objects in the process. This is not necessary. You could just update one object to the respective day:

```
var TodayPlusSeven = new Date();
TodayPlusSeven.setDate( TodayPlusSeven.getDate() + 7 );
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. It's just irritating when I need to do something like this several times on the page with different Today+x. What's the best alternative? The only option I see is instantiating several different dates.

Comment: If you're doing lots of stuff with dates, check out the Moment.js library.

Comment: @user2538011 Wrap it up in a function, that takes as two parameters the `Date` to be modified and the amount of days to add. In that case you have a shorter syntax throughout the rest of your code.